# Ruby on rails, how to query a database for objects without an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

This is my first stack overflow question, im very excited to be here! I just started coding this year so I am still a rookie and need your assistance with rails.

I am creating a web app that simulates a hockey draft pool. When a user creates a league, a bunch of player projections get automatically created and displayed. The user can then create teams within the league and assign projections to the teams. I created a model called player which is a way to associate a projection to a team. When the user adds a projection to a team they are actually creating an instance of a player that is associated to both. Is there any other way to do this having this player model?

One issue im having right now is how long it takes to query the database each time I display the available projections. Once a projection has a child player it should should no longer show up in the projection list. Here is the code that loops through all the projections and only displays ones without a child player.

```
<h3>Projections</h3>
<ol>
  <% @projections.each do |projection| %>
    <% unless projection.player %>
    <li><%= projection.player_name %><%= link_to "Assign to Team", new_player_path(leauge: @leauge, projection: projection.id)  %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Since there are 600 projections this takes 10-30s to query the database everytime the page is loaded. Is there a more effective way to do this?

Here are my models:

```
class Leauge < ApplicationRecord
  require 'csv'

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams
  has_many :projections
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  
  def create_projections
    CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('lib/seeds/projections.csv'), headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1') do |row|
      data = row.to_hash
      Projection.create!(
        player_name: data[:player],
        player_team: data[:team],
        goals: data[:goals],
        assists: data[:assists],
        points: data[:points],
        pp_points: data[:pp_points],
        hits: data[:hits],
        blocks: data[:blk],
        pim: data[:pim],
        fow: data[:fow],
        sog: data[:sog],
        leauge: self
      )

    end 
  end
end
```

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :projection
  belongs_to :team
end
```

```
class Projection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :leauge 
  has_one :player
  has_one :team, :through => :player
end
```

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :leauge
  has_many :players
  has_many :projections, :through => :players

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

THANKS

Comment: Use includes '@projections = Projection.includes(:players)'

Comment: This didn't work.  Its still showing every projection? Also :players needed to be :player do not create error.

@projections = Projection.where(leauge: @leauge).includes(:player)